# Problems setting up an association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Post model and a User model.  Users can love posts, this information is kept in a separate Love model rather than directly on the post because the User has to be able to see a record of the post's they've liked.

I have a migration like this:

```
    create_table :loves do |t|
      t.references :post, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
    end
```

User.rb

```
  has_many :loves
```

Post.rb

```
  has_many :loves
```

Love.rb

```
class Love < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :dinner
end
```

This association does not seem to work, whenever I try to love a post I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant User::Lofe
```

I realize the word "Lofe" may seem like a typo of Love, which is what I thought but I've searched through the entire codebase and there is no instance of `Lofe`.

In Rails console if I type `User.first.love` I will get an error suggesting `Did you mean? loves` this seems to indicate that the association exists (works with both Users and Dinners) but if I then type `User.first.loves` it will throw the same Uninitialized constant error.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with inflections. Rails could be automatically mapping "love" plural to "lofe". Try going to the console and using: "love".pluralize

Comment: I just ran `"love".pluralize` and got back `loves` so unless the inflector is different for the model names I don't think this would be the case.

Comment: Love is a really awkward choice for a model name as its not really countable or uncountable. For example "She has a love for donuts and coffee" and "he has had many loves in his life".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a little research and the problem is with Rails inflection engine. As you can see here: https://twitter.com/andypike/status/578214888465657856 and here: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2407-inflector-singularising-loves-to-lofe-but-pluralizing-love-to-loves apparently when using the word `love` you need to configure it by hand in `config/initizers/inflections.rb`